# Is there Axure RP alternative

Tags: web, prototype, user-experience, wireframe, axure

I'm wondering, if there is Axure RP alternative for a better price. I used other apps, but ended with Axure RP because of two fundamental advantages:

1. it's not only wireframe tool, but it lets me prototype whole web/app with functional demonstrations
2. it generates/exports prototype and customers can easily try personaly (it's HTML site and i upload it to my server and clients just get email with link to follow)

So, is there anything else like Axure RP meeting my two criteria with better price? All apps i've seen mainly fail in second condition.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - atomic.io lets you do both of these things.

You can go from low fidelity, right up to fully functioning prototypes that use things like logic, data, and variables.

You can also easily share an URL with anyone.  (see: https://atomic.io/learn/sharing)

And there is a free plan. :-)

[atomic.io](http://atomic.io)

Comment: You might want to provide a link to make it a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Harv - added now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [moqups.com](https://app.moqups.com) , it's a web app.
it lets you to make prototypes with linked pages and more . 
also it lets you to share your Design through a URL on its site.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of prototyping tools. 
https://www.cooper.com/prototyping-tools

It always depends on what your main goal to achieve is.
Justinmind (https://www.justinmind.com) is very close to Axure.

If you do not mind sharing your prototypes you can look into a bunch of different tools that are webbased (i.e. https://www.figma.com)